# Nginx rewrite only when root domain

Tags: nginx

I'd like to do an Nginx rewrite where I have two domains: domain.com and domain.net with the following rules:

1) If a user goes to http://www.domain.net/, he will be redirected to http://www.domain.com/
2) If a user goes to http://www.domain.net/anything_else.html the rewrite will not occur.

This is my failed attempt:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.domain.net domain.net;
  location / {
    rewrite / http://www.domain.com/ permanent;
  }
}
```

The correct format would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this works:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.domain.net domain.net;
  location / {
    rewrite "^$" http://www.domain.com/ permanent;
  }
}
```

Comment: needs to have `http://` in the URL: `location = / { rewrite ^ http://example.com permanent; }`

Comment: `^` is not recommended. "This is less efficient than the equivalent return directive, because it requires NGINX to process a regular expression, albeit a simple one (the caret [ ^ ], which matches the complete original URL)." https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately, @blueberryfields answer didn't quite work for me, had to do it slightly different:

```
server {
  (..)
  location / {
    rewrite ^(/)$ http://www.domain.com/ permanent;
  }
}
```

Note: Using nginx version 1.1.19